# "3 lines with a T" icon on Samsung Phone app call history

Tags: samsung, phone-app, call-history

What does that one icon with the 3 lines and T on call history of the Samsung Phone app? Why doesn’t it show for the other ones?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Android.SE]. Since manufacturers tend to customize their Android including the apps and their behavior, could you mention the app name, or at least the device model and Android version?

Comment: I do know it’s a Samsung I will have to wait to get the specifics

Comment: May be your question is understandable for native English speakers, I am am not and I don't understand what you are asking for. Your question is simply too short.